Error al conectar docker con PgAdmin - Failed to retrieve data from the server pgAdmin4
Conecté el contenedor Docker a pgadmin4, pero desde el primer momento aparece esta alerta:

y al crear una tabla dentro de la base de datos la tabla no aparece por este error, ya instalé una versión anterior de pgadmin y el error sigue igual

esa columna (wait_event_type) apareció en ls vista pg_stat_activity del postgresql 9.6, es muy probable que estes usando un postgresql mas antiguo

en efecto era un error de sintaxis con la versión de postgres al momento de levantar el contenedor en docker
